# get uses account/profile photo onedrive/microsoft API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have been able to get a users basic info & email address after successful authorization with the url:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I was hoping to also get the users main account/profile photo, but can't find any documentation on how to do this? Is there a way to do it? I am currently requesting 'wl.signin wl.skydrive wl.emails'

Answer (score 1):

You can get profile photo via following URL directly **(No need to use a access token)**:

> `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{USER_ID}/picture?type=large`

Just replace your user id in the URL above.

You can get different sizes of a user's picture, where SIZE is one of the following: **small** (to get a 96 × 96-pixel picture), **medium** (180 × 180), or **large** (360 × 360). If a particular size picture doesn't exist, the next-largest size picture that's available is returned. In any event, a 96 × 96-pixel picture is returned (unless no picture is associated with the user, in which case a default user picture is returned).

For more information, you can visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#user).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore.
Is there a new way? I'm getting https://js.live.net/static/img/DefaultUserPicture.png